# Understanding a pseudocode of Knapsack in recrusive

Tags: java, knapsack-problem

```
int knapsack(i, k){

    if(i=N){

        val= 0; //end of recrusive

        return val;
    }

    if (w[i]>k) // no space anymore

        val= knapsack(i+1, k); 

    else {

        a = knapsack(i+1, k) // i don't take with

        b = knapsack(i+1, k-w[i]) + v[i]; //i take with

        val= max(a,b); 

    } 

    return val;
}
```

My question is, what is N in this case ? In my Program for variables I have weight, value, maxweight and a LinkedList. Anyone can help me out ? Thanks

Comment: The place where you got this code from should have explained that.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no accurate explanation for this code where i got. just this comments : // calculates maximum value of the backpack problem with size
// k for objects with index i and lower.

Comment: it is not even a piece of working Java code.  And, is it that hard to properly format your code before posting?

Comment: its not, its a pseudocode that I'm trying to implement to java using LinkedList and ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

N is the number of elements in the input array/list. 
The first recursive call is `knapsack(0,k)`, and each recursive call increments `i` , until it reaches `N` and the recursion ends.

Comment: a and b ? what is that ?

Comment: @JeryozDimitar `a` is the result of the `knapsack` algorithm that doesn't include the i'th element and `b` is the result of the `knapsack` algorithm that includes the i'th element. The max of the two gives you the total result.